Article recommendations
I’m encountering an issue with article recommendations. After successfully building the model, I ran into an error when trying to activate it. The error message states:
“This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. First, would you give us some details? (We’re reporting this as error ID: -209902332).”
Has anyone else faced a similar issue or have suggestions on how to resolve it?

I did create a case it was a permission (Enable to bypass isEinsteinClient access restriction) that needed to be disabled in my org by the salesforce team.

Do you know what that was? More detail would help others raise their own cases in the future

Sorry for late reply @MattLacey
"Enable to bypass isEinsteinClient access restriction "
this the permission name that need to be disabled to make your model

no problem, thanks for the extra info!
